# AX 2012 table Rename Conflicts

Tags: c#, axapta

i have a question, i have a table with certaing name, used by some Web Services,  but i have to rename the table, for personal purposes, and i update the info in the Web Service, to point to the new table name, and it compiles fine.

Before making the change, the Web Service works like a charm, but after the  change i receive a 200 response, but without data (is a list, and now the list is empty).

I give an incremental Cil, and everything works, it does not give problema implementing the Services, and i update the references in the client side.

How can i solve this?

Comment: Some people suggests an Full Cil, but i cant do this, because is in production, so this is not an opcion

Comment: Have you tried refreshing the WCF information in the client configuration? For the BC too?

Comment: yes i have tried, and did not work, i will have to make a full cill, i think

Comment: Either you deliver the modification in production using a modelstore, so CIL compilation is already done and you just need to run the data dictionary synch; or you deliver using a model. Then you have to run full X++ compilation, full CIL compilation and data dictionary synch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Renaming a table is now partly broken in AX 2012 as not all relations to the table are renamed.

In former version all (internal) references to table and fields in the AOT was stored using the table id. Now it is *sometimes* stored as a string. Big mistake!

The best way to find these errors is to do a best practices check on your customization.

Comment: apreciate your help... after restarting the AOS, then database sync to AOT, and generate an incremental cil, all works again